# Nested If formulas in Excel

Tags: excel

I am trying to devise a If formula in excel base on string length in test but I only return zeros. I haven't found any errors so I am requesting to insight.

```
=IF(LEN(B3)=4,
    SUMIF(ForecastCombined!A:A,LEFT(A3,4)=B3,ForecastCombined!AL:AL),
    SUMIF(ForecastCombined!A:A,A3,ForecastCombined!AL:AL))
```

Comment: This doesn't make much sense `SUMIF(ForecastCombined!A:A,LEFT(A3,4)=B3,ForecastCombined!AL:AL)` You are saying, sum column `AL` where column `A` is equal to `Left(A3, 4)=B3` which is either going to return TRUE or FALSE. You are saying "When Column A has a value of TRUE or FALSE", which, even if it worked is probably not what you want to do. Get that SUMIF() formula working the way you want outside of this nested if, first.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help refactor your formula if you give us some test data and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You have two what seem to be logical tests the

"LEN(B3)=4" and the "sumif ... =B3,

if you want both to be true to continue then you need :

```
AND(test_1,Test_2)
```

if you only want one out of the two to be true to continue then :

```
OR(test_1,Test_2)
```

Can't guess more than that ...

So, this is my best guess:

```
=IF(AND(LEN(B3)=4,SUMIF(ForecastCombined!A:A,LEFT(A3,4)=B3),ForecastCombined!AL:AL,SUMIF(ForecastCombined!A:A,A3,ForecastCombined!AL:AL))
```